# How do I force HTTPS in Safari for macOS?

Tags: safari, security

How do I force Safari to always use HTTPS on macOS (11.4+)? Is there a way to do this from Safari settings, or is it only possible using additional software?

Comment: By "always", do you mean "only"?  https should certainly be the default. It might be possible to use a proxy for http that just bins the request.

Comment: This should be happening from the web site side these days.  It doesn't do any good to force the browser into an SSL-only mode if the web site isn't.  Are there really any web sites of any consequence left that don't redirect to their SSL equivalent these days?

Comment: @MarcWilson No, the question is how to have Safari coerce "http" to "https". In other words, if a site hasn't implemented HTTPS, shows a warning because it will be attempting HTTPS rather than HTTP, always. For example, this can be done with an extension like iVerify on iOS. In fact, it seems it will be the [default in Safari 15](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/423673/4395).

Answer (score 4):

The closest you can get in built-in Safari is

### Safari 15

‘**Upgrade known hosts to HTTPS**’ in Safari 15 under Debug → WebKit Internal Features.

It's enabled by default in Safari 15: https://trac.webkit.org/browser/webkit/trunk/Source/WTF/Scripts/Preferences/WebPreferencesInternal.yaml?rev=275449#L729

On launching Safari 15 for the first time, a What’s New page appears with the following:

> HTTPS upgrade automatically switches sites from HTTP to more secure HTTPS when available

### Safari 14

‘**Automatic HTTPS upgrade**’ in Safari 14 under Develop → Experimental Features.

It's disabled by default in Safari 14: https://trac.webkit.org/browser/webkit/trunk/Source/WTF/Scripts/Preferences/WebPreferencesExperimental.yaml?rev=273683#L388

It's described as

> Automatic HTTPS upgrade for known supported sites

---

When this feature was being tested, it only had 3 sites in the list.

https://opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit2/WebKit2-7611.2.7.1.4/Shared/HTTPSUpgrade/HTTPSUpgradeList.txt.auto.html

The list was changed from a `\n`-delimited text file to `HTTPSUpgradeList.db`, tested with 10M domains

> They can all search a list of up to 10M domains in <1ms.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=192736#c17

but I can't find this database anywhere so far.

Comment: On my Mac it's called "Automatic HTTPS upgrade" and appears not do do anything.

Comment: @orome Didn't realise it changed name, have clarified. I am seeing if I can find a list of hosts anywhere.

Comment: Ah, ok, so it's coming to 15 as a default feature. That makes sense.

Comment: I can't find this anywhere in Safari 15, and it appears not to be enabled by default either.

Comment: @orome It’s advertised in the What’s New prompt of Safari 15 (edited answer), if it’s not working for you that sounds like a separate bug!

Answer (score -5):

Being a developer, I need to quickly type in a local address at the URL field and having to keep writing "http://" or "https://' in front of a "api.test" is daunting and tiresome, so I went after a common solution used in the Linux world (to which, I still belong).

Edit the `/etc/hosts` file and add `https://<your_special_url` after localhost, so Safari can promptly interpret "api.test" as "https://api.test", and Bob is your uncle.

[image]

Comment: I see how you don't see what I saw in the OP. From my perspective, OP was trying to make it easier to type in a URL and for testing local sites. What I can (and have said) is that this approach eases typing the URL. Anyways I’m aware of different perspectives. Thanks for calling the attention to this point.

Comment: WOW! People here are really strict to the matter. Although I know SO's objective as a platform to discuss problem solving, I also understand one can contribute by pointing to complimentary course of actions. No problem, I don't make a living out of this one community, and won't bother being bothered. Good experience, tho.